# Is All AdMob Interstitial Ads are Muted by Default?

Tags: java, android, admob

I see a lot of android app show AdMob interstitial ads without audio that users can unmute than by clicking a speaker button in the ad.

Are all those interstitials muted by default?

Or Do I have to use this method for that [AdMob Global Settings](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/global-settings)

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
    });
    
//To inform the SDK that the app volume has been muted, use the setAppMuted() method:
MobileAds.setAppMuted(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
    });
    
    // 0.5 is the least you can reduce
    MobileAds.setAppVolume(0.5);
```

Set it up

Comment: I think you don't get my question. I am trying to serve muted ads that user can unmute.

Comment: MobileAds.setAppMuted(true); Is this method mutes ads?

Comment: MobileAds.setAppMuted(true) okk i will try